# opencv cascadeclassifier not loading .xml file

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, face-detection, cascade-classifier

I've been trying to load the .xml file on cascadeclassifier but it wont work.

Solutions on internet include using \ or / in file path but that does not work for me either

```
#creating a cascade classifier object
fc = 'C:/Users/abc/Desktop/cv/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface_default.xml'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fc)
img1 = cv2.imread("images.jpg")
grayImg  = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImg, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors = 5)
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    img1 = cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 3)
resizedd = cv2.resize(img1, (int(img1.shape[1]*7), int(img1.shape[0]*7)))
cv2.imshow("gray", resizedd)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

also tried:

```
#creating a cascade classifier object
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/abc/Desktop/cv/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface_default.xml')
img1 = cv2.imread("images.jpg")
grayImg  = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayImg, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors = 5)
for x,y,w,h in faces:
    img1 = cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 3)
resizedd = cv2.resize(img1, (int(img1.shape[1]*7), int(img1.shape[0]*7)))
cv2.imshow("gray", resizedd)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: _"but it wont work."_ .... Please post the actual error

Comment: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'